# Flutter auto fill Assists suggestions not working

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, dart

I have been working on flutter for the past 6 months and suddenly my Flutter auto-fill Assists suggestions stopped working.

I tried everything from upgrading flutter via `flutter upgrade` to updating my `dart Intellij plugin` but suggestions are still not working. Moreover my `flutter doctor` also shows no issues.

It is hampering my productivity a lot, please tell me what to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2448) you may have accidentally disabled the Quick assist option while working.

[image]

To re-enable the option go to Preferences/Settings in Intellij and turn this option to on.

[image]

Hope this helps.